# Validación / Comprobación FORM en jQuery "required"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formularios, required

Estoy intentado hacer lo siguiente:

- Tengo un botón de "Comprobar Pedido" en el que saco un "Modal" para mostrar un resumen del pedido.
- Estoy intentando, que al darle a comprobar pedido, revise antes si todos los requiered han sido rellenados.
- Estoy añadiendo los requiered, así:

  ```
  $('#familiaOI').prop('required',true);
  $('#disenyoOI').prop('required',true);
  $('#indiceOI').prop('required',true);
  $('#materialOI').prop('required',true);
  $('#TratamientoOI').prop('required',true);
  ```
- Se me ocurrió, ir validando todos los campos con IF .... aun que me parece una locura hacerlo así.

Agradecería vuestra ayuda y gracias de ante mano.

Comment: en el modal muestras solo resumen?

Comment: Sí, al darle al botón, paso los datos con jQuery a otro formulario (el que está en el modal) El problema que veo, que el Modal lo tengo en javascript, y no veo la forma de hacer que compruebe los datos, y si es correcto muestre el modal.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo usar la función `valid();`

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    if ($("#tu_id_form").valid()) {
        modal2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        alert("Datos requeridos");
    }
}
```

Otra opción es hacerlo desde javascript puro

```
var tu_formulario = document.getElementById("pedidos");
if (tu_formulario.checkValidity()) {
   modal2.style.display = "block";
} else {
   alert("Datos requeridos")
}
```

Comment: Mm, no me muestra el "alert", teniendo en cuenta que he añadido este codigo al javascript, no al jquery

Comment: cambiaste el id del formulario? puedes mostrar lo que imprime `$("#tu_id_form").valid()` ?

Comment: Si, la id es #pedidos, hago echo a $("#pedidos").valid() ??

Comment: `console.log($("#pedidos").valid())`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function me imprime

Comment: puedes probar la segunda opción que te deje?

Comment: El problema de este código, es que si hay algun campo ya con required, nada más entrar te manda el alert, y si está sin required, que los voy añadiendo por jquery, nada mas entrar, aparece el modal, ya que cumple la condición

Comment: Lo logico es que si esta con required y no esta completado, te mande la alerta, si agregas un input que no esta con required claramente quiere decir que no es necesario, por ende te dejará pasar.

Comment: No entiendo entonces porque me manda el "alert" nada más entrar

Comment: Hola de nuevo, he pasado el Modal a jQuery, así mucho más sencillo, se te ocurre algo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82016/discussion-between-sioesi-and-javier-avila-fernandez).